# How to remove the new line when reading from UNIX process groovy?

Tags: unix, groovy, string-concatenation

In a groovy script, I have a variable which is a returned value from a Unix process.

`def text = ['bash', '-c', command_to_execute].execute().text`

I use its `text` variable to concatenate with some other strings

`def concatanated_text = "${var1}.${var2}.${text}.full.zip"`

When I print the variable `concatanated_text`, the result will be in two lines like below.

```
file.name.2017
.full.zip
```

But when I manually assign the value to `text` variable it will look in one line as below.

```
def text = "2017"
file.name.2017.full.zip
```

I want to concatenate this string in one line. Please help me with a solution.

Comment: New line character after `2017` when read from process

Comment: Is there a way to remove the new line when reading from the process?

Comment: Thank you @Qiu. I Added a ```| tr -d '\n'``` to the command_to_execute. so it removed the new line.